# How to set output of terminal to external VGA display

Tags: ssh, debian, shell, xrandr

I have laptop with broken screen and external monitor that i can connect to laptop via VGA port. Is there any way how to set output of shell(I have no GUI on installed debian) to VGA monitor? I can connect only with SSH. I googled around and found some manuals with xrandr, but when i try to run xrandr, it returns only "Can't open display". Any ideas how to send output to external monitor?

Comment: `xrandr` is for configuring the graphical GUI (X.Org), thus it can't be applied here. There have been similar questions in SU but no definite answer can be given, based http://superuser.com/a/896003/243625 which basically is saying that it will work if you get the laptop BIOS to use the external display.

Comment: On the other hand, if you aren't interested necessarily to get the external display active during boot, you might have some luck with configuring the GPU driver parameters (load the module from SSH session after boot), if it is compiled as a kernel module, and if it has any suitable parameters for selecting the output connector. This all depends on the GPU in the laptop, which you've not mentioned.