# How to trace the boot process in Windows 10?

Tags: windows-7, windows-10, boot

I have a Windows 10 + Xeon E3 (i7-4770 equivalent) with a Samsung 840 SSD and 32GB RAM, but the boot times are worse than what I experience with a Windows 7 + i5 with an ADATA SP900 and 8 GB RAM.

I fear that the issue mentioned in [Why is the boot sequence no more visible with a Gainward GTX 1060 Phoenix?](https://superuser.com/questions/1172010/why-is-the-boot-sequence-no-more-visible-with-a-gainward-gtx-1060-phoenix) could affect it, but I would like to track the time required at boot by the various drivers and modules.

How can I have a trace of the boot process including time required and IO activity? I already know that Task Manager can provide those informations for the Startup applications, but I refer to the boot part, before the login screen.

Comment: Boot time are really OS dependant. Moreover, it's not the same setup. It's not logic to compare boot times of two differents installs of Windows.

Comment: @Neil Ok, thanks. I'm still interested in having a sort of boot log to improve my system. I think the question is not strictly limited to the reasoning that pushed me, it can be useful in general.

Comment: [follow my steps from my answer](https://superuser.com/a/976646/174557) of the duplicate topic. I shows how to trace it.