# Disable laptop screen and use external screen as primary, just like a desktop

Tags: laptop, multiple-monitors, hdmi

I have disconnected the laptop screen from the motherboard, and now I'm using an external display, which is connected via HDMI (see first image below).

It's already set to only show on Display 2 on screen configurations but I can't see the boot screen or nothing like that. The screen only shows something when it's loading windows. The VGA also doesn't work.

Edit: I need to see the boot screen because I'm trying to do a dual boot with Ubuntu.

External display, which is connected via HDMI:
[[image: external display, which is connected via HDMI])](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RmI3e.jpg)

Answer (score 2):

You cannot see the boot process on the external monitor, since the BIOS does not
have the drivers necessary for using HDMI. The BIOS will only use the primary
connection (that you have disconnected) in VGA mode.

If your laptop screen is broken, you can still use the computer, but not the
BIOS. When Windows boots up after the BIOS, it will detect the HDMI connection
and use it for display, so the Windows login is where you will begin
to see anything.

Your situation is entirely normal and correct for your setup.

Comment: But i'm trying to make a dual boot with Ubuntu. That is the problem :(

Comment: I don't see the connection between your post and dual boot. If you wish to update `grub` boot, you don't need the BIOS.

Comment: Everytime i go to "advanced startup options" and check the usb, the notebook stays running but no image.

Comment: I don't really understand. I think it would be better if you add all the pertinent details to your post, including screenshots.

Comment: i have added some images @harrymc

Comment: With that setup you're probably not able to see your BIOS at all, right? So what harry said would still apply. In order to have "pre-boot" images you'd need to use the internal connector because you BIOS is likely set to only use that during boot.

Comment: This answer is wrong. Bios only cares about finding the right GOP driver or legacy option ROM, end. Display handling is simply a matter of what's coded in said firmware (which I'm afraid some laptops OEM may have screwed up). As a matter of fact my Asus X756UX, if booted with an HDMI cable already plugged in, will show the UEFI interface on the external monitor.. in all its 1280x1024 glory.

Comment: @mirh: The subject here is the poster's BIOS, not yours. You're off-subject.

Comment: You also didn't say a thing about OP's laptop that he didn't already know (not that anybody could have anyway, since not even the manufacturer is mentioned). The theory isn't right though, especially considering the [literally](https://superuser.com/questions/895988/how-do-i-change-which-monitor-my-computer-uses-at-boot/#1596797) [dozens](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/312325/grub2-not-showing-on-hdmi-monitor/#312326) of workarounds he still could have tried.

Comment: @mirh: Post up your answer and leave mine in peace.