# Display Bios to external Monitor at System Start

Tags: bios, external-display, dell-inspiron

Recently, My laptop lcd got broken after a fall so I unplugged it from the motherboard.
I am trying to connect it with an external monitor but unable to get my bios display onto external monitor. I tried `FN+F1` which is external display function key on my keyboard. Monitor light turns to blue which shows it is attached but it stays blank. I have bios password setup. Wonder, That is making an issue here?
Please advise, I am unable to search a solution for this specific case.
Laptop is Dell Inspiron 3537.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Disable laptop screen and use external screen as primary, just like a desktop](https://superuser.com/questions/1432696/disable-laptop-screen-and-use-external-screen-as-primary-just-like-a-desktop)

Comment: Ummm nope. actually my setup is exactly the same. and I happened to get the bios screen with random strokes to function keys. Also, I had a bootable usb plugged in as well (with intention to get a boot order menu). next i had to reboot again. but couldnt get the screen next time. now I am wondering is there any secret key combination to get the display.

Answer (score 2):

From the [Dell community](https://www.dell.com/community/Inspiron/Dell-3537-Bios-on-external-hdmi/td-p/7908003): "The system will not complete POST without a working internal screen attached. You will need to replace the display panel."

That said, if you plug in the display again, the OS might not "know" it's broken and POST (though hidden). If it's just the back-light that's broken, you might be able to see a *very* dim, grayish, display without it, and back-lights are usually more easily replaced.

Also, <kbd>F4</kbd>, with or without  <kbd>Fn</kbd>, [might be the key to press for an external monitor](https://forums.tomsguide.com/threads/i-have-a-dell-inspiron-15-3537-and-the-screen-is-broken-ive-been-using-my-tv-as-a-monitor-via-hdmi-and-it-wont-display-any-l.145728/) on the Dell 3537.

Comment: Right. I will try. plus the screen was long dead but it might be useful to pass POST. Thnx.

Answer (score 1):

My laptop is Dell Inspiron 15R 5521, maybe this can help, you just enable booting via legacy, on my laptop it can display Bios on the External Monitor, after a few seconds on the Main Monitor BIOS display, it will immediately switch to the External Monitor, I use HDMI and it should if using VGA it will be the same, if your LCD Laptop is Broken you can search on youtube to enable setting Legacy Boot, to enable Legacy Boot usually you disable Secure Boot previously..