# Dual monitors, UEFI windows 10 Pro HDMI and DVI. Swapping the cables changes identity' from 1 to 2, 2 to 1, boot still posts on the right monitor. why

Tags: multiple-monitors, hdmi, uefi, dvi

Dual monitors, both DVI connections, one HDMI adapter to use both outputs on GTX 730. Monitor on left primary, right secondary, boot posts to secondary monitor. I swap the cables so both monitors switch output on card, choose left monitor as primary yet boot still posts on the right side monitor. Does UEFI Identify a monitor by name and have it registered as primary boot preference?

Comment: What do you mean by "both DVI connections, one HDMI adapter"?

Comment: Check out the answer here for some reasons: https://superuser.com/a/896003/673426. It's generally up to the video card, so yeah it can choose a primary. It can be the primary monitor's fault too if it doesn't come out of sleep mode fast enough for example

Comment: Both monitors are DVI, one adapter on one cable to connect to the HDMI connection on the card so to use both HDMI and DVI outputs.  Swapping the cables doesn't change the boot screen from appearing on the right side monitor but it does change The OS positions of the monitors between primary and secondary.